# Doubt regarding assumption of domain when one isn't given

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, soft-question

> Calculate $f(x)=\dfrac{49}{x^2}+x^2$ at the points where $\dfrac{7}{x}+x=3$.

Now if $D_f\subseteq \mathbb R$, then this has no solutions since $\dfrac{7}{x}+x=3$ has no solution in $\mathbb R$. But if $D_f=\mathbb C$, then this equation yields solution:

$\dfrac{49}{x^2}+x^2=\Big(\dfrac{7}{x}+x\Big)^2-14=9-14=-5$ (obviously here $x\notin \mathbb R$)

Now my doubt may be silly (I apologize for that), but until now at the high school level, we have been advised to assume the domain of function to be $\mathbb R$ except when given otherwise. But here the domain must obviously be assumed to be $\mathbb C$ to yield a solution. So what should be assumed as the domain of any function in general when any specific domain isn't mentioned?

Comment: You've gone too deep. I can't tell you how many times in the 9th class book(this is Selina ICSE I speak of, I am helping a few people using that book) I saw something like this, where you have to assume that $x$ satisfies an equation that no real $x$ can satisfy, then you have to find some other function of $x$ (All this comes in that expansions chapter). I would ask you to bring this up with your teacher, but there's no problem (at *that* level) in proceeding without acknowledging the domain. (Of course, rigorously speaking the question is unclear, since without the domain you cannot proceed)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I disagree. OP did not go too deep. OP actually thought about the problem, rather than performing the robotic work of manipulating one expression to get another. Instead, OP actually thought about the problem, and realised it is not well formed. It's not that the OP went too deep. The problem authors didn't go deep enough.

Comment: @5xum Correction, I will put it this way : the authors did not expect him to go so deep. Big difference, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Ah, now we agree. I just don't want OP to feel bad for doing the right thing :)

Comment: @5xum Thanks. My father went to Slovenia about $10$ years ago. He's been to Lake Bled and eaten at an Indian restaurant in Ljubljana. We have some nice pictures at home!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what should be assumed as the domain of any function in general when any specific domain isn't mentioned?

Nothing. There is no "general function domain". If the domain of a function is not implicitly clear from the context, then the text must explicitly mention that domain, otherwise, it is unclear.

Comment: So, should I assume that the question mentioned in the text was unclear?

Comment: @DevanshKamra It's a bit unclear, yes. Not tragically so, as the solution still stands, but it is a good example of how one must be careful when putting together "simple" questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help (+1).